# How do I create a standard content template for Book pages in Drupal 6?

Tags: templates, drupal-6, module

I am working on a Drupal 6 site and need to create a Book where each book page has the same basic structure. I'd like to use a shared template.

Is there a Drupal module that allows me to create book pages from a shared template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the actual machine name of your Book node type is *book*, then the corresponding template file is *node-book.tpl.php*